# Why doesn't my while loop abort after I enter 0?

Tags: c

```
char inputvalue=7;
char zerovalue=0;

while(inputvalue != zerovalue)
{
    scanf (" %c",&inputvalue);
    printf("%c\n",inputvalue);

}
```

Why doesn't my while loop abort after I enter 0?

Thank you for your answer. Question part b:
How do I fix this, so it would work as expected?

```
char inputvalue[100]='48';
char zerovalue[100]='0';

while(inputvalue != zerovalue)
{
    scanf (" %c",&inputvalue);
    printf("%c\n",inputvalue);

}
```

Comment: what you take `char` type to compare `int` ? For comparing `char`   use `'0'` or `48`.

Comment: Because the ASCII value for `'0'` is 48, not 0.

Comment: It might be the leading space: " %c"

Comment: "would work as expected"??? The code you posted is not even compilable. That means that you need to read a book on basic syntax of C declaration, not write random code and expect other people to whip it into shape for you.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
char zerovalue=0;
```

to

```
char zerovalue = '0';  // 0 != '0'
```

Comment: Explanation: `0` is numeric value 0, which is typically used to terminate strings, whereas `'0'` is the character that looks like 0. `'0'` typically has numeric value `48`, as far as I remember, which is not equal to `0`!

Answer (score 1):

You are entering the character '0' which is not the same as the integer 0.

'0' is in the middle of the ASCII character set.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this answer follows the edit to the question (part b)

I don't know why you suddenly declared the `char`s to be `char[100]`s.

ASCII `0` is either `(char) 48` or `(char) '0'` *not* `'48'`.

The following works (and compiles)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char inputvalue = 0;             //initialised to 0, just so no undefined behaviour can happen
     char zerovalue  = '0';           //this is ASCII '0' (== 48)

     while(inputvalue != zerovalue)
     {
        scanf (" %c",&inputvalue);
        printf("%c\n",inputvalue);
     }
}
```